# multiple Json to excel and vice versa

Tags: gratis, linux, microsoft-excel, json, parser

- The application I'm looking for must be web based or even better if it  run on linux 64 bit, I have fedora
- Must be free
- Must support UTF8, because of arabic strings

Suppose you're building a multi language website

```
en.json:
"register": "Please register"
fr.json:
"register": "S'il vous plait enregistrez vous"
```

You know english so you translate the first key, you don't know french so you have to send the json as an excel to someone who knows french like so

```
"register"    ""Please register"    ""
```

3 columns, he sees the key, he reads the word you want to translate, and translate it. You receive the excel, the program splits the excel into 2 json files again according to the keys

Here's a small sample `en.json` that I use

```
{
  "fname": "First Name",
  "lname": "Last Name",
  "mname": "Middle Or Father's Name"
}
```